# Which is the correct way to store and load selected elements in a html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, parameters

I'm developing a web project which users can select some options in a form and submit a job. For this purpose, it is necessary to store selected elements (checkboxes, etc) to load the selected elements afterwards.

I reviewed a project that does the following: Each time users select an element (checkbox), it adds to the current url the following:

```
http://localhost/myapp#variable=TEMPERATURE
```

And if you paste this url, the checkbox variable whose value is TEMPERATURE is selected. Is the hash (#) an appropiate way to select elements? Does Hash launch a change event or something?

The solution I though to implement was to include selections as parameters:

```
http://localhost/myapp?variable=TEMPERATURE
```

and if you load this url, do the job with jquery (parse url parameters and select elements)

Note that the elements are not fixed. If you select, for example, the variable temperature, new elements are loaded and If user selected one of the elements in the stored query, I need to select it too but I think I can handle it.

My question is what is the different between this two approximations and which is the most suitable to do the job I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` formally know as the [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or request parameter, is basically a variable passed to the server.

The `#` formally know as the [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) or simply hash, is originally used to position pages so that the top of the element identified by the fragment `id` attribute is aligned with the top of the viewport.

Use the Query string (`?`) if you want the processing to happen in the **Server**.

Use the Fragment identifier (`#`) if you want the processing to happen in the **Web Browser**.

I'm guessing form the `jQuery` tag that you want to implement this in the **Web Browser** so take a look at libraries such as [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) that make implementing this functionally simple and clean using a mechanism called `Router`s, which will use the URL hash.

Comment: Yes, i want to implement it in the client side. The only thing is that it will be a select with saved selections. The user selects one, and the elements have to be selected automatically. I'll take a look to Backbone.js. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Benajmin Just one more question... "#" launchs an event? For example, If you include #26256542 in this post it highlights. Is there in the onload event a custom function to highligh the post or is there an event in the dom which is launched when #... exists?

Comment: @mannuk You can get the hash from `window.location.hash` and you can listen to the `hashchange` event using `$(window).on("hashchange", function() { ... });`, note the `hashchange` event is not fired when the page loads, and make sure to test your code in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin, I've accepted your answer. I definitely use the hashchange event. For this reason I asked you about something similar twice. If I make progress I'll post some code.